# Interesting MATCH AGAINST issue: not searching some words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match-against

I have a table like this:

```
|====brand=====|======title================|
|....Apple.....|...iPhone 5 32 GB..........|
|....Sony......|...Bluetooth Headset.......|
```

And i am using **FULL TEXT SEARCHING** basically like this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  MATCH(brand,title) AGAINST ('some words') as score
FROM
  table
```

So when i searched **headset**, mysql giving 1.812121 score truely.
But when i searched **iphone**; mysql giving 0 score.

**P.s:** ft_min_word_len = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

> A natural language search interprets the search string as a phrase in natural human language (a phrase in free text). There are no special operators. The stopword list applies. In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match. Full-text searches are natural language searches if no modifier is given.

So the bit about common words sounds likely.

Comment: So i need to use LIKE operator?

Comment: I think you can use Boolean mode to disable the common words filter. Or could use LIKE instead, or could build a search index, or even use a dedicated full-text search product, or a number of other solutions.

Comment: The boolean mode option does not solve this problem.

Comment: Hmm, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html says, "Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics: They do not use the 50% threshold."